# Hide load more button when the result is <= to the limit CI

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm having a trouble with a "load more" button. I want the button to hide if the result is (1) less than the limit of 20 (2) if there are no more results e.g. everything is already displayed. Currently, it is still visible despite my best efforts.

This load more button should be hidden because my limit is 20 and it has only 4 results:

[image]

**Controller Codes:**

```
public function get_topic($user_id='')
    {
        $this->load->helper('text');
        $page = $_GET['page'];
        $value['posts'] = $this->user_model->get_userpost($user_id,$page);
        $this->load->view('themes/default/user/user_topic_post',$value);
    }
```

**Model Codes:**

```
// get topic post
    function get_userpost($user_id,$page)
    {   
        $offset = 20 * $page;
        $limit=20;
        $this->db->where('status',1);
        $this->db->where('user_id',$user_id);
        $this->db->limit($limit);
        $this->db->offset($offset);
        $this->db->order_by('id','DESC');
        $query = $this->db->get('threads');
        return $query;
    }
```

**user_topic_post Codes:**

```
<?php
$CI = get_instance();
$i = 0;
foreach($posts->result() as $post):
$i++;
?>
<tr>
    <th scope="row">#<?php echo $i ?></th>
    <td><a href="<?php echo base_url("topic/".$post->thread_slug);?>"><?php echo $post->title; ?></a><br/>
    <small class="num-result"><?php echo strip_tags(word_limiter($post->content,20)); ?><br/><b>
    <?php 
    $posted_date = $post->created_at;
    $now = time();
    echo timespan($posted_date, $now, 1).'&nbsp'.lang_key('ago'); ?></b></small></td>
    <td class="num-result text-center"><?php echo custom_number_format($post->post_view); ?></td>
    <td class="num-result text-center"><?php echo custom_number_format($CI->threads_model->countTopicReplyByTopicId($post->id)); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
endforeach; //foreach
?>
```

**My js Codes:**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            userpost(0);

            $(".load-more").click(function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var page = $(this).data('val');
                userpost(page);

            });

        });

        var userpost = function(page){
            $(".user-topic-post-loading").show();
            $(".load-more").show();
            $.ajax({
                url:  "<?php echo base_url("user/get_topic/".$account['id']); ?>",
                type:'GET',
                data: {page:page}
            }).done(function(response){
                $(".user-topic-post").append(response);
                $(".user-topic-post-loading").hide();
                $('.load-more').data('val', ($('.load-more').data('val')+1));
                if(response == ""){
                    $(".load-more").hide();
                }
            });

        };      
        </script>
```

Comment: Your description is a bit unclear, could you revise it so it is easier to understand? Perhaps use bullet points

Comment: I`ll add video for it it is ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to send two variables to your done function one being if there are no results to be displayed under the condition if the results are less than 20, and the other being the view data to append.

You could try something like this:

PHP:

```
public function get_topic($user_id = '') {
    $this->load->helper('text');
    $page = $_GET['page'];
    $items_per_page = 20;
    $posts = $this->user_model->get_userpost($user_id, $items_per_page, $page);
    if ($posts->num_rows() < $items_per_page) {
        $msg = 'done';
    } else {
        $msg = 'success';
    }
    if ($posts->num_rows() > 0) {
        $body = $this->load->view('themes/default/user/user_topic_post', array('posts' => $posts), true);
    } else {
        $body = '';
    }
    $this->output->set_content_type('application/json');
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode(array('msg' => $msg, 'body' => $body)));
    $this->output->_display();
    exit;
}

public function get_userpost($user_id, $per_page, $page) {
    $this->db->where('status', 1);
    $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
    $this->db->limit($per_page);
    $this->db->offset($per_page * $page);
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'DESC');
    return $this->db->get('threads');
}
```

JS:

```
var userpost = function (page) {
    $(".user-topic-post-loading").show();
    $(".load-more").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url("user/get_topic/" . $account['id']); ?>",
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            page: page
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (response) {
        $(".user-topic-post").append(response.body);
        $(".user-topic-post-loading").hide();
        if (response.msg == "done") {
            $(".load-more").hide();
        } else {
            $('.load-more').data('val', ($('.load-more').data('val') + 1));
        }
    });

};
```

You should also consider validating that the `$page` get var is an integer. Otherwise some user could put in a string, and although it will be escaped by default with query builder, it will certainty return an error.

Comment: Its working now but the load more button doesnt show up even there still data that needed to be load

Comment: how many results do you have in total? because i'm not sure how you are confirming that more data needs to load if you only have 4 results

Comment: try changing $posts->num_rows() <= $items_per_page to $posts->num_rows() < $items_per_page

Comment: i have 19 total results and i change the limit from 20 to 10 just to test the codes it loads 10 result but the remaining 9 will never be load since the load more button doesnt show up.. I will try it later I’m taking my lunch now. By the way merry christmas dude

Comment: you too man! pretty sure it was the condition, just do some troubleshooting around that area

Comment: Its working now thank you dude thank you for you Christmas gift ^_^